# Google Cloud PubSub/Datastore Error 13 & 14: "GOAWAY received" and "TCP Read/Write Fail"

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

Sorry for the long title. Having some issues randomly pop up (every handful of hours, but not on a regular schedule, could be anywhere from 3 hours to 8) when streaming data from Cloud PubSub into Cloud Datastore using Cloud Functions.

Source is a Node.js 6 script that receives an HTTP Post with info, writes to PubSub topic, then publishes topic to Cloud Datastore.

It is a modified version of this:
https://github.com/CiscoSE/serverless-cmx

Errors:

This first one happens sometimes with TCP Write instead of Read, but it's the same error.

```
ERROR: { Error: 14 UNAVAILABLE: TCP Read failed
    at Object.exports.createStatusError (/user_code/node_modules/@google-cloud/datastore/node_modules/grpc/src/common.js:87:15)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (/user_code/node_modules/@google-cloud/datastore/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:1188:28)
    at InterceptingListener._callNext (/user_code/node_modules/@google-cloud/datastore/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:564:42)
    at InterceptingListener.onReceiveStatus (/user_code/node_modules/@google-cloud/datastore/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:614:8)
    at callback (/user_code/node_modules/@google-cloud/datastore/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:841:24)
  code: 14,
  metadata: Metadata { _internal_repr: {} },
  details: 'TCP Read failed' }
```

And:

```
ERROR: { Error: 13 INTERNAL: GOAWAY received
    at Object.exports.createStatusError (/user_code/node_modules/@google-cloud/datastore/node_modules/grpc/src/common.js:87:15)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (/user_code/node_modules/@google-cloud/datastore/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:1188:28)
    at InterceptingListener._callNext (/user_code/node_modules/@google-cloud/datastore/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:564:42)
    at InterceptingListener.onReceiveStatus (/user_code/node_modules/@google-cloud/datastore/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:614:8)
    at callback (/user_code/node_modules/@google-cloud/datastore/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:841:24)
  code: 13,
  metadata: Metadata { _internal_repr: {} },
  details: 'GOAWAY received' }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there is a similar error for [other services](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-spanner/issues/234) and the workaround is just to retry.